# Retrieving Storyboard element that is outside of the frame

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm working with an xcode storyboard. I was resizing a label and it pushed a UIImage outside of the frame, so I can no longer see it. I can't grab it. How do I move it back on the frame so I can see it?

I can verify that it is in my tableview cell, because it is still listed under the content view on the left bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also select the element from you view controller scene from the document outline (on the left) and move it around with your keyboard arrow keys (double click so it's grey and not blue, if it's blue you will navigate the scene).  I use the arrow keys most often to position my elements relative to each other.  Holding the option key while moving the mouse to different elements gives alignment and distance guidelines to other objects while you move with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

On the left side of the storyboard, expand the elements for your `UITableViewCell`. You should see the `UImage` listed. Click on it, then go into the right menu and change the x,y coordinates. It'll now put it back to where you can see it and edit it.

Also just be careful about having your `UIImage` object as the bottom layer. I've hidden things from myself when they were accidentally put as the bottom layer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way for Xcode 10 and above:
Navigate to the storyboard
Choose the controller of the controller scene you want to see the element of
Under size inspector, select 'Freeform' from the Simulated size dropdown
Increase the width/height and hit return. 
After you have laid out all elements in the canvas and no longer want to see elements which are outside of frame, revert back to 'Fixed' simulated size under Size inspector.